# Python scrapy: how to scrape link by detecting class in the same level?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Want to get the links within `<h1>` which has span `class="puzzle-type"`.

From below, link1 and link2 will be scraped, except link3.

By now I have to get all `<h1>` tags, and then check if they have such a class and get the link. It will cost more time if a page has too many `<h1>` tags. Is there a simpler way to do so? Thanks.

```
<h1>
    <span class="puzzle-type" >A</span> 
    <a href="link1.com">link1</a>
</h1>
<h1>
    <span class="puzzle-type" >B</span> 
    <a href="link2.com">link2</a>
</h1>
<h1>
    <a href="link3.com">link3</a>
</h1>
```

Python:

```
   def parse(self, response):
        for h1 in response.xpath('//h1'):
            if h1.xpath('.//span[@class="puzzle-type"]').extract_first():
                url = h1.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xPath Axes](https://way2tutorial.com/xml/xpath-axes.php). This is my solution:

```
response.xpath('//h1/span[@class="puzzle-type"]/following-sibling::a')
```